# adjust sticky footer for responsive webdesign

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, responsive-design

I am working on responsive webdesign in ASP.NET MVC 5. I have dashboard which got header, middle body and footer. I want header and footer of per-define height and dashboard takes middle part, meaning user won't score up or down. I have created the javaScript and jQuery plugin, where I am calling plugin on resize and load page and if height of view-port is less than 786 (less than ipad portrait size) then add stickyfooter class to footer div else remove class, which working fine, only issue when I increase size from 787 to greater, it remove stickyfooter class but it left gap between footer and dashboard middle body... I am not how to fix this. I guessing css clear both but figure out how!

secondly I have notice when I reload page it is fine, is just when I resizing my viewport

### JQuery Plugin

```
(function ($) {

 $.fn.stickyFooter = function () {

    $(window).bind('load resize', function () {

        var viewport_height = $(window).height();

        var footerHeight = $('.footer_wrapper').height();

        var viewport_width = $(window).width();

        var footerTop = $('.footer_wrapper').position().top + footerHeight;

        var Wrapper_Height = (viewport_height - ($(".footer_wrapper").height()) - ($(".navbar-header").height()));


            if(viewport_width < 768)
            {
                if (footerTop < viewport_height) {
                    $('.footer_wrapper').addClass("stickyFooter").css('margin-top', 10 + (viewport_height - footerTop) + 'px');
                }


                $(".navbar-toggle").click(function () {
                    if (footerTop < viewport_height) {
                        $('.footer_wrapper').addClass("stickyFooter").css('margin-top', 10 + (viewport_height - footerTop) + 'px');
                    }
                });

                $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").height("auto");

                $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").height("auto");
            }
            else if(viewport_width > 767)
            {
                if ($('.footer_wrapper').hasClass("stickyFooter"))
                {
                    $('.footer_wrapper').removeClass("stickyFooter")
                }

                //adjust height of Functions_Panel_Wrapper 
                $(".Functions_Panel_Wrapper").css("height", Wrapper_Height - 1 + "px");

                //adjust height of Function_Page_Wrapper 
                $(".Function_Page_Wrapper").css("height", Wrapper_Height - 1 + "px");

            }           
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

### HTML

```
<body>
  <!--*************************** Header ***********************************-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top header_wrapper"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             @Html.ActionLink("London College Of Music", "Home", "Dashboard", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
             <!--<a href="@Url.Action("Home", "Dashboard")" class="logo"></a>-->
          <!-- <a class="navbar-brand logo-nav" href="#"><img src="~/ImagesAndIcons/Images/LCM.jpg" style="max-width:30%;height:auto;" /></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!--<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>-->
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>



    </div>
</div> <!--end header-->

<div class="body-content">

    <!--*************************** Main Body ***********************************-->

    <div id="body_main_wrapper">
        <!--Functions Panel Wrapper (left-side)-->
        <div class="Functions_Panel_Wrapper">
            functions lists.....
        </div>

        <!--Functions Page Wrapper (right-side)-->
        <div class="Function_Page_Wrapper">
            @RenderBody()
        </div> <!--end Function_Page_Wrapper-->           
    </div> <!--end body_main_wrapper-->

        <!--*************************** Footer ***********************************-->
      <!-- <div class="footer_wrapper navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">-->
    <div class="footer_wrapper">
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="footer_Title_Wrapper">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                </div> <!--end footer_Title_Wrapper-->
            </div> <!--end container-->
        </footer>
    </div><!--end footer_wrapper-->
    </div> <!--end body-content-->
```

### css

```
html, body{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#body_main_wrapper{
display:table;
width:100%;   
margin-top:0;
background-color:grey;
}

.body-content{
margin-top:-20px;
}

.Functions_Panel_Wrapper{
width:20%;
float:left;
background-color:red; 
}

.Function_Page_Wrapper{
width:79%;
float:left;
margin-left:1%;
background-color:pink;
}

.footer_wrapper {
width:100%;
min-height:80px;
left:0;
background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want the footer to remain at the bottom of the page even inf the body doesn't fill that far?  If so, you certainly don't need to use JavaScript.  There are plenty of CSS solutions, such as: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: correct, then leads my 2nd problem, which is main body of dashboard takes rest of height, currently i am doing in JQuery plugin, is some reason is coming gap between middle body and footer!!!!!!!!!!